# Knockoutjs viewmodel structure

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I still have some problems structuring my knockoutjs models. 
The data which I got from server looks like this:

```
var data = {
    Creation: "2012-01-01T00:00:00Z",
    Id: 3,
    LastActivity: null,
    Name: "Foo",
    Permissions: {
        IsAdmin: false,
        IsInternal: false,
        // ... some more boolean
    },
};
```

Now I create a model like this:

```
var getDetails = function (user, edit) {
    UserModel = function() {
        var self = this;
        user = user || {
            Id: 0,
            Username: '',
            Creation: new Date(),
            LastActivity: new Date(),
            Name: '',
            Permissions: {
                IsAdmin: false,
                IsInternal: false,
                // ... some more boolean
            },
            Stores: []
        };

        this.Id = ko.observable(user.Id);
        this.Username = ko.observable(user.Username);
        this.Creation = ko.observable(user.Creation);
        this.LastActivity = ko.observable(user.LastActivity);
        this.Name = ko.observable(user.Name);

        // how handle the permissions ???

    };
```

The Permissions like `IsAdmin, IsInternal, etc` I have to use in checkedboxes. All are booleans. 
Now my questions, how is the best way to handle the permissions object. Create an own model? Or can I use something like this:

```
 this.Permissions.IsAdmin = ko.observable(user.Permissions.IsAdmin);
```

Comment: create a view model for the permissions type ie `PermissionsModel = function(permissions){ IsAdmin = ko.observable(); //... etc etc }` then in your `UserModel` add `self.Permissions = new PermissionsModel(user.Permissions);`

Comment: okay, I thought this is the right way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would approach this by creating another view model for the permissions type since it is a complex type and needs to store multiple values. Hooray Object-Oriented Programming!

For example:

```
var PermissionsModel = function(permissions){ 
    var self = this;

    self.IsAdmin = ko.observable(permissions.IsAdmin || false);
    self.IsInternal = ko.observable(permissions.IsInternal || false);
}
```

Then in your `UserModel` add a `Permissions` property like so:

```
var UserModel = function(user, edit) {
    var self = this;       

    self.Id = ko.observable(user.Id || 0);
    self.Username = ko.observable(user.Username || "");
    self.Creation = ko.observable(user.Creation || new Date());
    self.LastActivity = ko.observable(user.LastActivity || new Date());
    self.Name = ko.observable(user.Name || "");
    self.Permissions = new PermissionsModel(user.permissions || {});
}
```

Now, you can pass your `data.permissions` object directly off to your new view model and let it worry about instantiating those properties.

---

A small and semi-related note: You can assign your default values directly in the `observable` function. The plus side of this is that you no longer need to create an anonymous object within your class. Also, when you go to add/edit your model, you don't have to keep track of that object anymore. You can just change/add the properties directly.